# Why am I unable to monitor a specific Windows process in Zabbix?

Tags: performance, process, monitoring, zabbix

I am trying to monitor a specific Windows process in Zabbix and it does't work. 
I tried using Zabbix's own example and it still doesn't work, what am I getting wrong here?

Zabbix own example of monitoring iexplore.exe page faults is proc_info[iexplore.exe,pf,avg] and this is exactly what i've used. (See attached screenshots)

The monitored machine is a win7x64 vm with iexplore.exe running.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaUeL.png)[image]

Comment: Please describe what "it does't work" means.

Comment: @Richlv Doesn't work as doesn't collect any data. (the work that the monitor should do). This was the wrong key to use on a windows host, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I did not use the correct key
for a Windows process, the correct key is:

```
perf_counter[\Process(iexplore)\% Processor Time]
```

To get a list of all available performance counters in Windows, go to cmd and type:

```
typeperf -qx (or typeperf -qx > monitors.txt as its a huge list)
```